# What is svn cat abbreviating in Subversion?

Tags: svn

Subversion offers the `svn cat` command which retrieves a file as it existed in a particular revision number and displays it.

Sample usage:

```
$ svn cat -r 3 http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/readme.txt
This is a README file.

INSTRUCTIONS
============

Step 1:  Do this.

Step 2:  Do that.
$
```

I understand what it is doing and how to use it, but I have a difficult time recalling it much of the time since I can't figure out what it is representing/ abbreviating.

Is it just paying homage to our furry feline friends? Does it stand for capture?

Comment: Are you familiar with `cat`, the unix command?

Comment: Unfortunately no I am not. Admittedly I am from a Windows OS background. This is further reason to take the time to educate myself on the Unix OS. Recognizing the meaning of this would have been trivial if I had more Unix experience.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It comes from the [Unix concatenate command - cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29)

> The cat program is a standard Unix utility that will output the contents of a specific file and can be used to concatenate and list files. The name is an abbreviation of catenate, a synonym of concatenate.

Comment: It is ironic, though, that svn took the name from cat since `svn cat` exists purely to dump a file (at a given revision) to stdout, whereas `cat` existed to concatenate files and outputting to stdout was a side-effect that happened to be more broadly useful.